# Changing image color - semi-transparent pixels completely different

Tags: image, go, image-processing

I am trying to develop a Go function that will replace pixels of a specified color in a PNG image with a different color, but also change the color of the semi-transparent pixels.

Original image:
[image: Text]

Resulting image:
[image: Text]

Resulting image zoomed in:
[image: Text]

As it can be seen when comparing, fully gray pixels were successfully colored, but semi-transparent ones turned kind of blue/green instead of transparent pink. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my code snippet with comments.

```
    img, name, format, width, height, err := FromURLGet(request.URL) // fetches image data from the URL, img is an image.Image object
    if err != nil {
        return res, errors.New("Error: could not fetch image")
    }

    upLeft := image.Point{0, 0}
    lowRight := image.Point{width, height}
    newImg := image.NewRGBA(image.Rectangle{upLeft, lowRight}) // creates a new image of same size for drawing

    selectedColor, err := ParseHexColorFast(request.Hex) // retrieves color.RGBA based on provided hex
    if err != nil {
        return res, err
    }

    // loop through existing pixels
    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            // get current pixel color and convert it to uint8
            r, g, b, a := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
            r2 := uint8(r >> 8)
            g2 := uint8(g >> 8)
            b2 := uint8(b >> 8)
            a2 := uint8(a >> 8)

            // if pixel is the non-transparent gray color, replace it with selected
            if r2 == 189 && g2 == 188 && b2 == 188 && a2 == 255 {
                newImg.Set(x, y, selectedColor)
            } else if r2 == 0 && g2 == 0 && b2 == 0 && a2 == 1 {
                // if pixel is fully transparent,  keep it the same
                newImg.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{r2, g2, b2, a2})
            } else {
                // else if pixel is a different color or semi-transparent, set it to required color but keep transparency a2

                fmt.Println("current RGBA", r2, g2, b2, a2)
                fmt.Println("setting RGBA for X, Y", x, y, selectedColor.R, selectedColor.G, selectedColor.B, a2)

                newImg.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{selectedColor.R, selectedColor.G, selectedColor.B, a2})
            }
        }
    }

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
err = png.Encode(buf, newImg)
```

Am I correctly setting the Alpha channel? Since the colors from the prints I have appear as supposed to.

For example:
current RGBA  118 117 117 159
selected color RGBA 214 30 110 255
setting RGBA for X, Y 31 29 214 30 110 159

Comment: You are constructing `color.RGBA` with color data not pre-multiplied by `a2`. If `selectedColor.A` is `255`, try `newImg.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{selectedColor.R*a2/255, selectedColor.G*a2/255, selectedColor.B*a2/255, a2})`. I am not fully aware of whether you need to consider gamma correction here as well. You might get a result that looks kind of right, but is still wrong/could look better.

Comment: That change definitely helped! It could still look better like you said, now I get all of these pixels in different transparency of black, instead of different colors. I need to play with it more. Thank you!

Comment: I thought about it, and I have reasons to believe you need to gamma correct. Alpha cannot really know what color you are going to blend with, so it cannot afford to discriminate and should apply in linear RGB. Try to 1. convert selectedColor to linear, 2. pre-multiply, 3. convert selectedColor back to sRGB. You can learn how here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Transformation (ignore the parts about CIE XYZ) This also might help https://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/tag/srgb/